# Why the value of this ListNode dont change in Python?

Tags: python

By given a sorted linked list, delete all duplicates such that each element appear only once.(link:https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/)
i already got a solution but i'm confused the other solution below.

```py
class Solution(object):
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        curr = head
        prev = ListNode(0)
        # prev.next = curr
        rec = prev
        while curr:
            while curr.next and curr.val == curr.next.val:
                curr = curr.next
            prev.next = curr
            print('prev1:',prev)
            prev = curr
            print('prev2:',prev )
            curr = curr.next
            print('rec  :',rec)
        return rec.next
```

input:

```py
[1,1,2,3,3]
```

output:

```py
[1,2,3]
```

print:

```
prev1: ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}}}}
prev2: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}}}
rec  : ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}}}}
```

Question 1: why `rec` is not the same to `prev2` here?

```
prev1: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}}}
prev2: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}}
rec  : ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}}}}
prev1: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}
prev2: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}
rec  : ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}}}
```

Question 2: why `rec` is `ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}}}` here?

Comment: Q1: You're changing `prev`, but `rec` only gets assigned a value once, why do you expect them to be the same? Q2: hard to say, you're also not providing a full example, so it's impossible to tell how you construct your input - can you update the question to be complete?

Comment: @Grismar Thanks.                                                                                   
Problem link:https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/discuss/164798/Python-solution                                                          
Other solution link:https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/discuss/164798/Python-solution

Comment: @Grismar It's really appreciated for your detail but i added the followed questions on your answers by bold.

Comment: The changes you made to the answer didn't actually fit with the answer and were rejected by others - if you have comments or further questions, please ask in the comments below the answer and I'll try to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You first construct `prev`: `prev = ListNode(0)`

Then you point `rec` to it: `rec = prev`, so `rec` now points to a new node that has value `0`.

`curr` starts at `head`, as it's passed into the function and the loop starts by moving `curr` forward in the list from `head` until it reaches the last node that still has the current value, matching the value of `head`.

Then `.next` of `prev` (and therefore of `rec`, it's the same node) is pointed to `curr`.

`prev` is then updated to point to `curr` (with value `1`), but `rec` still points to the same node with value `0`.

`curr` is then updated to point to `curr.next` (with value `2`) and the process repeats.

This answers your first question: `rec` is not pointing to the same node as `prev`, which is what is printed as the value for `prev2:`.

As the process continues, linking in every last node that has a repeated value, skipping all the previous nodes with the same value, you end up with `rec` pointing to the first node in the chain with value `0` (as initialised) and all the nodes with unique values in the runs starting at the `head` and onwards.

That answers your second question - it starts with a `0` for the same reason as in question 1 and the rest is exactly what  you would expect it to be, if you realise that the node with value `0` is the start of the chain that is constructed.